# datastage error - odbc function "SQLNumResultCols"

Tags: oracle, datastage

I am trying to select table from an oracle database using datastage.

In the ODBC Connector, If i do

```
select *
from Table_Name
```

I get this error -

> 'ODBC function "SQLNumResultCols" reportted: STATE=102:Native Error
>   Code = 0: Msg = [IBM(DataDirect OEM)][ODBC 20101 driver] 251'.

However if i use -

```
select cast(colA as varchar(50) as A,
       cast(colB as varchar(50) as B
```

instead of

```
select *
from table_name
```

it works just fine. The data type of these columns is `NVARCHAR2`.

Is there a way to directly get it from

```
select *
from table_name
```

(there are about 20 columns in each of these tables)

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix. Changed nvarchar parameter in odbc file